# Difference between <string> and <string.h>?

Tags: c++, string, header, header-files

How come this code

```
std::map <std::string , int> m;
m["a"]=1;
```

compiles with (I'm using MSVC 2010)

```
#include <string>
```

but not with

```
#include <string.h>
```

?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

- `<string.h>` contains old functions like `strcpy`, `strlen` for C style null-terminated strings.
- `<string>`  primarily contains the `std::string`, `std::wstring` and other  classes.

Comment: It should also be noted that using `string.h` is deprecated within C++. If you need the functionality contained within, you should use the header `cstring`. This more or less completely bypasses the issue of "What's the difference between these two" because it's very obvious that one is from the C library.

Answer (score 24):

`string.h` is a C header not a C++ header, period!

Comment: Do you mean that when I do a couple of files .h/.cpp I should remove the .h or is your answer just for euh, like sdk files?

Comment: I think, it's better to say the other way: `<string> is C++ header, not a C header.`

Answer (score 16):

`<string.h>` is cstring - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

`<string>` is the c++ string class - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/

Edit per Nicol Bolas comment below and a bit of googling:

`<cstring>` will usually import the same things as `<string.h>` but into the `std` namespace.
`<string.h>` will usually import everything into the global namespace.
It appears to depend on the library implementation you're using though according to my googling.

Personally I only ever use `<cstring>` if I need C style string helpers.

Comment: `<cstring>` is not a synonym for `<string.h>`. `cstring` puts stuff in the `std` namespace (it may also leave them outside of the `std` namespace), while `<string.h>` does not.

Comment: Using C style `.h` headers is deprecated in C++.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav To be deprecated it would have to have been part of the  standard to begin with, which it never was.

Comment: @PeterWood : Check out Annex D [D.5] C++03.

Answer (score 13):

`string.h` is C's header file while `string` is C++'s header file.

Comment: `<string.h>` can be considered C++ header file also. :)

Comment: Nope! <cstring> is to be used with C++.

Comment: Well yes C header is compatible with C++, but it is deprecated and we should be using cstring.

Answer (score 9):

`<string.h>` contains C-library string functions. `strlen`, `strcmp`, etc.

`<string>` contains the definition for `std::basic_string`, which has the typedefs `std::string` and `std::wstring`. That's the difference.

They really have no relationship at all, outside of the fact that they both deal with strings.

Answer (score 5):

They are entirely different headers.

`<string>` is C++ `string` class

`<string.h> or <cstring>` defines functions to manipulate C strings and arrays

Answer (score 3):

As stated, `string.h` and `cstring` are C headers (while `cstring` is basically a C++ wrapper for `string.h`), containing functions for C strings, which are `char[]` terminated by `'\0'`. You want to use the c++ class string, which header  is `<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `<string.h>` is just used for C and `<string>` for C++. So including `string.h` wont work.

Answer (score 1):

- edited after Adrian's comment

1. In **C**, to use the old C-style string features (including `strlen(char*)`), we write this:

   ```
    // C
    #include <string.h>
   ```

   And this is the only way in C. Including this header will define and declare some actual functions (like `strlen`, `strcmp`, ...) in the global scope.
2. And such way of inclusion continues in **C++**, as the C++ compilers are supposed to be compatible with the most (99%) of C codes. The following identical code includes the old C-style string features (including `strlen(char*)`):

   ```
    // C++
    #include <string.h>
   ```
3. In **C++** to avoid confusion, as the language team renamed the old headers to put away as legacy, we are recommended to write this, rather than 2.:

   ```
    // C++
    #include <cstring.h>
   ```
4. *Or*, as **C++** prefers to omit the ".h" at the end, we write this,

   ```
    // C++
    #include <cstring>
   ```

Summary: 1., 2., 3., and 4. are the same thing indicating the old C style string features (including `strlen(char*)`).

5. On the other hand, **C++** has a new objective container class named `std::string`, and to include the new C++ style string class , we write:

   ```
    // C++
    #include <string>
   ```

Summary: 5. is the only way to bring the new C++ features of string class named `std::string`.

*Plot twister*: `<string>` in itself imports `<cstring>` (in most compilers). Therefore, for using the old C-style string features, all five examples I've presented will work without error. For using the new C++ string class, again, `<string>` is the only way.

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused. In actual fact, on most systems, `#include <string.h>` is (or *may be*) equivalent to `#include <cstring>`. As pointed out in other answers.

Comment: @Adrian Mole - My gosh, you are right, I tried to have a too much expansive explanation for every cases (rather than concise as others did for fewer cases), then I got trapped by myself. I've just edited the answer immediately. Thank you! *afterthought*: It turned out that my code including <string.h> worked with the std::string class because another header <iostream> in my compiler still includes <string>, and the <string> includes <cstring>.

Comment: Note also that `<string>` often includes `string.h` but, IIRC, it's not required by the Standard to do so. But I could be wrong.

Comment: You are right again, there is no absolute rule in compatibility or inclusion of other headers (when there are some things going on, it is possibly the gratitude from the compiler environment), so sometimes I also encounter errors when I only use <iostream> and a string class, which has an error with this compiler in this computer and no error with that compiler in that computer. (Not the different versions of C++, but different compilers)

Answer (score 0):

`<string.h>` is a C standard library header while `<string>` is a cpp in fact all the c standard header files have `.h` extension an non of cpp have `.h`.

Answer (score 0):

string.h is for c compatible c++ string class
string is for pure c++ string class