# std::getline get error in JNI

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using jni and want to read file from path, i used:

```
while (std::getline(file, str)) {
...

}
```

but it get an error : Function 'getline' could not be resolved, i have added:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>
```

and they are Ok. How do i resolved this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
#include <string>
```

instead of:

```
#include <string.h>
```

The latter one is the C variant and will not have the std namespace. Also see:

[Difference between <string> and <string.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257665/difference-between-string-and-string-h)